# Strcpy Segmentation Fault C

Tags: c, strcpy

I am learning some new things and get stuck on a simple strcpy operation.
I don't understand why first time when I print works but second time it doesn't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *name;
    char *altname;

    name=(char *)malloc(60*sizeof(char));
    name="Hello World!";
    altname=name;
    printf("%s  \n", altname);
    altname=NULL;
    strcpy(altname,name);
    printf("%s  \n", altname);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: you aren't allocating more memory for altname/name.

Comment: wow, that is inefficient. `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 byte, and if you are going to allocate a fixed amount of memory, why use `malloc()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `altname` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *name;
    char *altname;

    name=(char *)malloc(60*sizeof(char));
    name="Hello World!";
    altname=name;
    printf("%s  \n", altname);
    altname=NULL;
    // allocate memory, so strcpy has space to write on ;)
    altname=(char *)malloc(60*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(altname,name);
    printf("%s  \n", altname);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The problems start here:

```
name=(char *)malloc(60*sizeof(char));
name="Hello World!";
```

You replaced the value returned by `malloc` with a string literal.

1. You leaked memory (since you can't regain the pointer value returned by `malloc`).  All calls to `malloc` are matched with a corresponding call to `free`.  Since that pointer value is gone, the opportunity to call `free` with that pointer value is also gone.
2. You further on write to a NULL pointer, which is undefined behavior (which in your case, produced a segmentation fault).

Comment: @juanchopanza - I made the change to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first time, you are making `altname` point to the same place as `name`. This is OK, because `name` points to a valid `char*` (the first element ofthe  `"Hello World!"` literal)

```
// both point to beginning of "Hello World!" literal
altname=name;
```

The second time, you attempt to copy the *data* pointed at by `name` into the place pointed at by `altname`, which at this stage points to NULL. So you attempt to write to NULL, which is the source of the error.

`strncpy` requires that the destination buffer be writable, and large enough to copy the source string's data into. You need to make `altname` point to a buffer that is large enough for the contents of the string `name` points to.

```
altname = (char*)malloc(60*strlen(name)+1); // +1 for nul terminator
strcpy(altname, name);
```

Also note that when you set `name = "Hello World!"`, you leak the memory it originally pointed to. You need to free that first:

```
free(name);
name = "Hello World!";
```

Comment: No, actually, he sets altname=NULL, and attempts to copy to there, so null pointer exception, I would say.

Comment: @Greycon Oops, I missed the NULL. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign value to `altname` which has no space to store. First allocate memory to `altname` then assign

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *name;
    char *altname;

    name=(char *)malloc(60*sizeof(char));
    name="Hello World!";
    altname=name;
    printf("%s  \n", altname);
    altname=NULL;
    altname=(char *)malloc(sizeof(name)); // allocate memory
    strcpy(altname,name);                 // Now assign 
    printf("%s  \n", altname);
    return 1;
}
```